# I get a null value in laravel orm

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a poblem with mi Laravel models: My table users has a idUser and the one entries has a foreign key user_id. This column is the user to make the entry. so l have these models:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table='users';

    public function entries(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Entry');
    }
}
```

the Entry model:

```
class Entry extends Model
{
     //Indica la tabla del modelo
     protected $table='entries';

     // Relación one to may con tabla categorías
     public function products(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
     }

     public function user(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'idUser');
     }
}
```

In the test I have:

```
use App\Entry;

Route::get('/test', function () {

    $entries=Entry::all();
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
       echo $entry->idEntry. "   " ;
       echo $entry->idProduct. "   ";
       echo $entry->count. "   ";
       echo $entry->cost."   ";
       echo $entry->date. "    ";
       echo var_dump($entry->user). "    ";
       echo "<br>";
    }

    die();
    return view('test');
});
```

The result is a null

Comment: You have `die()` at the end of your route definition. maybe this could be causing the problem?

Comment: No. the $entry->idEntry, $entry->cost and others are showed. the vardump is the null. it must be a problem with the relations

Comment: This wasn't described in your question... Share your migrations to be more helpfull.

Comment: Daniel the result is  3   2  10  625   2020-04-17 00:57:15 but the result in var_dump($entry->user) is an empty array

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the primary key attribute as 'idUser' in your User model,

You just need to include this line in your model.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'idUser';
```

Check more about this in documentation [enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)